# How to correctly send request via Cellular network only in iOS

Tags: ios, networking

My problem is clearly 2 cases:

- (1) Send request URL1 via wifi only
- (2) Send request URL2 via cellular only

I know `Reachability` utility (both Apple's code and AFNetworking/Alamofire code) and `allowsCellularAccess` property (in NSMutableURLRequest and NSURLSessionConfiguration).

But these solve the case (1) only (as I set `allowsCellularAccess` to NO).
The case (2) is not ensured, as the request can run via cellular or wifi (if available). Even if I check the status via Reachability for cellular only, there's still some abnormal cases as described in this documentation [Restrict Cellular Networking Correctly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/Platform-SpecificNetworkingTechnologies/Platform-SpecificNetworkingTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH212-SW9)

Is there any better way to ensure Cellular network only, using Objective-C or Swift?

Answer (score 4):

#### You can do it in socket with IP_BOUND_IF:

1. use "getifaddrs" included in "ifaddrs.h" to get interface addresses:

```
struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
NSInteger success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
if (success == 0) {
    // Loop through linked list of interfaces
    temp_addr = interfaces;
    while(temp_addr != NULL) {
        if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
            // Get NSString from C String
            NSString* ifaName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name];
            NSString* address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *) temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
            NSString* mask = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *) temp_addr->ifa_netmask)->sin_addr)];
            NSString* gateway = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *) temp_addr->ifa_dstaddr)->sin_addr)];
            NSLog(@"%@;%@;%@;%@",ifaName,address,mask,gateway);
        }
        temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
    }
}
```

Then you'll see the output like this:


*lo0;127.0.0.1;255.0.0.0;127.0.0.1

pdp_ip0;10.9.163.185;255.255.255.255;10.9.163.185

en0;10.0.0.6;255.255.0.0;10.0.255.255*

("pdp_ip0" means the cellualr interface)

2. use "if_nametoindex" in "net/if.h" and "setsockopt" in "sys/socket.h" to send msg through the specified interface

```
int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
int index = if_nametoindex( "pdp_ip0");
int suc = setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_BOUND_IF, &index, sizeof(index));
```

Then connect the socket, you'll see you have connect the server through cellular interface

Comment: Then connect the socket? This is not clear. U mean we need to call some HTTP request after

Comment: Plase explain more on this